# Finding groups of clustered data points

Tags: t-sql

I have a table which records events:

```
create table #events
(  intRowId int identity(1,1),
   intItemId int,
   intUserId int,
   datEvent datetime)
```

It's a big table with many millions of rows, recording events against several thousand items and tens of thousands of users.

There's a select group of ten itemIDs I want to look for, but only when they occur in a certain pattern: I'm trying to find rows where all ten of these items have events registered against them for the same userID and close together in time, say 5 minutes.

I have absolutely NO IDEA how to go about this. One would assume partitioning is involved somewhere, but help, even just somewhere to get started, would be much appreciated.

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: start hint: filter by userID, group in 5 minute grouping using a CTE

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show some example data and expected results.

Comment: Do the events need to always occur in groups of ten? Some sample data would help, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you want statistics about items id: 1, 2, ... , 10.
First create a table EventByItems:

```
CREATE TABLE EventByItems
(  
   intRowId int identity(1,1),   
   intUserId int,
   datEvent datetime,
   intItem1 int,
   intItem2 int,
   intItem3 int,
   ...
   intItem10 int
)
```

Then use query to populate this table:

```
SELECT intUserId, datEvent, 
   SUM(pvt.[1]), SUM(pvt.[2]), SUM(pvt.[3]), ... , SUM(pvt.[10])
FROM #events
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(intItemId)
    FOR intItemId IN ([1], [2], [3], ... , [10])
) AS pvt
GROUP BY intUserId, datEvent
```

Now we can do some work with that table. For example we can update it to fill gaps according your logic. Or we can do queries like that:

```
SELECT
  intRowId,
  intUserId,
  datEvent
FROM
  EventByItems AS E
WHERE
  ((intItem1 > 0) OR EXISTS(SELECT * 
                            FROM EventByItems 
                            WHERE intUserId = E.intUserId
                             AND intItem1 > 0
                             AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, datEvent, E.datEvent) <= 5
                             AND intRowId != E.intRowId ))
  AND

  ...

  AND
  ((intItem10 > 0) OR EXISTS(SELECT * 
                            FROM EventByItems 
                            WHERE intUserId = E.intUserId
                             AND intItem10 > 0
                             AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, datEvent, E.datEvent) <= 5
                             AND intRowId != E.intRowId ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so below you'll find a working example which does what you want. I'm assuming that events don't have to appear in tens.

But the solution is very crude, and will run slow, especially if you increase number of items/users.

Temp table with pre-selected events would help with performance in my solution, but what you really need are windowed functions like in Oracle..

```
DROP TABLE #events
GO

create table #events
(  intRowId int identity(1,1),
   intItemId int,
   intUserId int,
   datEvent datetime)
 GO 
   
insert into #events (intUserId,intItemId,  datEvent)
select '1','1','2013-05-01 10:25' union all --group1
select '1','2','2013-05-01 10:25' union all --group1
select '1','3','2013-05-01 10:26' union all --group1
select '1','7','2013-05-01 10:25' union all
select '1','8','2013-05-01 10:25' union all
select '1','9','2013-05-01 10:26' union all
select '1','1','2013-05-01 10:50' union all --group2
select '1','2','2013-05-01 10:52' union all --group2
select '1','3','2013-05-01 10:59' union all 
select '1','1','2013-05-01 11:10' union all --group3
select '1','1','2013-05-01 11:12' union all --group3
select '1','3','2013-05-01 11:17' union all --group3
select '1','2','2013-05-01 11:25' union all
select '1','1','2013-05-01 11:31' union all
select '1','7','2013-05-01 11:32' union all
select '1','2','2013-05-01 11:50' union all --group4
select '1','2','2013-05-01 11:50' union all --group4
select '1','3','2013-05-01 11:50' union all --group4
select '1','1','2013-05-01 11:56'
GO 
    
DROP TABLE #temp
GO
select 
     e1.intRowId as intRowId_1, e1.intItemId as intItemId_1, e1.intUserId as intUserId_1, e1.datEvent as datEvent_1
    ,e2.intRowId as intRowId_2, e2.intItemId as intItemId_2, e2.intUserId as intUserId_2, e2.datEvent as datEvent_2
into #temp
from #events e1
join #events e2
    on e1.intUserId=e2.intUserId
    and e1.datEvent<=e2.datEvent
    and e1.intRowId<>e2.intRowId
where 1=1
    and e1.intUserId=1
    and e2.intUserId=1
    and e1.intItemId in (1,2,3)
    and e2.intItemId in (1,2,3)
    and datediff(minute,e1.datevent,e2.datevent)<6
order by 
    e1.intRowId, e2.intRowId
GO

select distinct
    * 
from (
    select 
        intRowId_1 as intRowId, intItemId_1 as intItemId, intUserId_1 as intUserId, datEvent_1 as datEvent
    from #temp

    UNION ALL

    select 
        intRowId_2 as intRowId, intItemId_2 as intItemId, intUserId_2 as intUserId, datEvent_2 as datEvent
    from #temp
) x
order by 
    datEvent, intRowId
```